# Connect JMS client to Apache Kafka

Tags: jms, apache-kafka, hornetq, apache-kafka-connect

I have a 3rd party system pumping data into HornetQ using JMS. I need to replace HornetQ by Kafka but I cannot change the 3rd party system. What is the correct way to get the data into kafka.

I googled around and found [JMS-Client](http://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/kafka-jms-client/docs/index.html#confluent-s-jms-client-for-apache-kafka) and [kafka connect](http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/intro.html). After reading both documentation I'm confused and not sure which one is the right one.

Has anyone any experience with this and can give me some hints on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The right way is to use the JMS-Client because it's an implementation of the JMS API specification but with the Kafka wire-protocol. It means that you can use this client in your 3rd party system and using Kafka instead of HornetQ on the other side. It means that at least you need to add this dependency to the 3rd party system in order to use this JMS implementation for Kafka instead of the HornetQ one.

Comment: Kafka JMS Client is part of Confluent Enterprise 3.2 or higher.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Kafka JMS Client when you want to replace a JMS Broker with Apache Kafka

Use the Kafka JMS Connector when you want to integrate Kafka with a legacy JMS broker and send messages between the two different systems.